# Why did Babe Ruth want Henry Aaron's baseball card?

Tags: dialogue, the-sandlot

In the movie [*The Sandlot (1993)*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108037) there is a scene where Benni Rodriquez has a dream where Babe Ruth comes to him to give him a pep talk on being a legend.

At a certain point, Babe picks up a baseball card and says:

> Henry Aaron... I don't know why, but can I have this kid?

And Benni tells him, "sure".

So presumably, the audience does know why Babe would want the baseball card. I get that he was a famous baseball player and his card is a collectible, but what special significance would it have to Babe Ruth and what does this line have to do with the plot of the movie or even the scene in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Remember that this is a dream so it's not actually based on reality.**

Babe Ruth would have no way of knowing the "importance" of Henry "Hank" Aaron in the future...so it's based on Benni's perception.

Essentially, Babe Ruth held the all-time Home Run record (714) for many years until it was beaten by Hank Aaron in 1974.

So, no, Ruth would not *actually* have known why he wanted the card but in Benni's mind it's something he might have desired to respect his own record being broken.

Comment: Oh yeah of course! I didn't realize Hank Aaron had broken Babe's home run record so this makes sense. Also the movie is set prior to 1974 so that would make sense why the two characters didn't know why he was significant yet. He hadn't broken the record yet.